# Error 3030002 when trying to set contract steps

Tags: smart-contract, cleos, docker, python

I'm following steps from [`exchange-tutorial-python`'s README file](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/tree/slim/programs/exchange-tutorial-python) inside the Docker container:

```
$ docker run -it eosio/eos
# nodeosd.sh 2>/dev/null &
# cleos wallet create
Creating wallet: default
Save password to use in the future to unlock this wallet.
Without password imported keys will not be retrievable.
"PW5J9S9Qwxewc8gnVpQBEedm4fGhFh4dhDzRtkAuFDPvZjsCVSLMa"
# cleos create key; cleos create key
Private key: 5JpkUEGHLnrmQJWpDjvo9nnHUnHtsx6d7ukir6uUyiKk64vyjVq
Public key: EOS7rGcyooUtUt3bVN23LjYNS9mxi9cN6bgD7VYP6FghWdLSQQMrD
Private key: 5KhkBhKGwcyBnktoFNjPt7XHYC1jRmQUe7hcgVVEWVsDDrzMCra
Public key: EOS4xfYEwxfB3PLvmDqGebCj3UHBxn3tF2v97RzKAugssxBwh4Y56
# cleos wallet import 5JpkUEGHLnrmQJWpDjvo9nnHUnHtsx6d7ukir6uUyiKk64vyjVq
imported private key for: EOS7rGcyooUtUt3bVN23LjYNS9mxi9cN6bgD7VYP6FghWdLSQQMrD
# cleos wallet import 5KhkBhKGwcyBnktoFNjPt7XHYC1jRmQUe7hcgVVEWVsDDrzMCra
imported private key for: EOS4xfYEwxfB3PLvmDqGebCj3UHBxn3tF2v97RzKAugssxBwh4Y56
# cleos create account eosio myuser EOS7rGcyooUtUt3bVN23LjYNS9mxi9cN6bgD7VYP6FghWdLSQQMrD EOS4xfYEwxfB3PLvmDqGebCj3UHBxn3tF2v97RzKAugssxBwh4Y56
executed transaction: 65da2c9e179157e5084d8b2e003bd3f2a65736d6d1d08a151cfb5f18a5512753  352 bytes  102400 cycles
#         eosio <= eosio::newaccount            {"creator":"eosio","name":"myuser","owner":{"threshold":1,"keys":[{"key":"EOS7rGcyooUtUt3bVN23LjYNS9…
# cleos set contract eosio.token /contracts/eosio.token -p eosio.token@active
Reading WAST/WASM from /contracts/eosio.token/eosio.token.wast…
Assembling WASM…
Publishing contract…
Error 3030002: signatures do not satisfy declared authorizations
Ensure that you have the related private keys inside your wallet and your wallet is unlocked.
Error Details:
transaction declares authority '{"actor":"eosio.token","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it.
```

but it fails on the last step due to missing signatures. What I'm missing?

Comment: Did you create the eosin.token account?  That first parameter in the set token command is the account to which the contract is attached.

Comment: Probably not, I'm testing it using fresh Docker container as shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `set contract` operation takes the account name as its first parameter (`eosin.token` in your example).  If this account doesn't exist, if cannot set the contract.  In your example above, you create a new account called `myuser`.  You need to create an account called `eosin.token` in order to execute the `set contract` call you show.